# cakephp getting value of textfield in model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Hi I have dynamically added input fields on my add view. When I submit my form I want all them input fields to be concatenated into one string and stored in a single database field.

Im trying to achieve this using the beforeSave method of cakephp but I can't seem to find out how to get the values of a text field within the Model.

```
function beforeSave($options)
{
    $result = '';
    $bool = true;
    $counter = 0;

    while($bool == true)
    {
    $result = $result + ',' + $this->data['Variable']['selectOptions' + counter];
    }

    return true;
}
```

Anyone any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paste your code please... Though you can get your data in `$this->data` in beforeSave function...

Comment: It seems obvious to me, that you should never manipulate data in a Model. You should modify the data in a Controller, before sending it to the model.

Comment: So get the values in the controller stick them into a string and then set a text field in the view with the values and save?

Comment: You don't want `'selectOptions' + counter++`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion (from MVC point of view) it would be better to concatenate the fields in controller and then unset unnecessary fields before saving the model...

Answer (score 0):

after get the post values in model you can merge the array values into a single variable like this..

```
<?php 
   $var = array('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6');
   $new_values = implode(',',$var);
   echo $new_values;
?>
```

You can retrieve these values after saving to database.

Answer (score 0):

this might not be the perfect answer but might give you some head start in that direction

```
function beforeSave($options = array()) {

    pr($this->data); // <= show data you intend to save
    exit;
}
```

use foreach to loop the data array ($this->data) and perform concatenation on the values and assign the concatenated string to the feild name

```
function beforeSave($options = array()) {
foreach  ($this->data['Variable'] as $key=>$value)
{
$feildflag = strstr($key, 'selectOptions');
if($feildflag){
$concatenatedstring .= $value;
}
}
$this->data['Variable']['your_feild_name'] = $concatenatedstring ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic form field should looks like in a foreach loop:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Model.field][', array());
```

In your model:

```
function beforeSave($options)
{
    if(!empty($this->data))
    {
         $this->data['Model']['common_field'] = implode(",", $this->data['Model'['field'];
         unset($this->data['Model']['field']);
    }  
}
```